# Symfony2 form, how options is set?

Tags: php, symfony

Ok, let me straight.

I know how to use `setDefaultOptions` and set new default custom options and its value in `FormType` like that:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('custom' => 'custom value'));
}
```

But, I want to know how the other default options are set and finally available in

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
}
```

I tried to trace it from `$this->createForm` in symfony2 controller, but then I stuck in the `FormFactory::createNamedBuilder` function of symfony2:

```
public function createNamedBuilder($name, $type = 'form', $data = null, array $options = array())
```

Any hint/answer is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for inherited options. Each form have a parent form define in getParent() function.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all availaable options for any form type : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html

Additionnaly, you can find in documentation the specific options for each form type provided by symfony. For example, text form : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html